# How can I check column sql Belong to the same row

Tags: php, sql

My database is called pica 
It has the following table called gallery

Example:

gallery==>

```
id   pic1
__  ___
1    picture1.jpg
2    picture2.jpg
3    picture3.jpg
```

How can I check column sql Belong to the same row in php

Example:
I want to check that picture1.jpg Belong to id 1 and
picture2.jpg Belong to id 2
After that  I get a message Verified ,
It's that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a query like this:

```
$row = $db->getOne("SELECT count(*) as count 
                    FROM pica WHERE id = 1 
                    AND pic1 = 'picture1.jpg'");

if ($row['count'] > 0) 
{
     print 'message Verified';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to check `$php_pic` and `$id` are in same row or not

Do it this way :

**Method 1**

```
 /*Fetch records*/
      $sql = 'SELECT id,pic1 from gallery where id = $id';
      $rs= $mysqli->query($sql);  /* fetch details */

      $id = $rs['id'];
      $pic1 = $rs['pic1'];

    /* match using php */
        if ($id == $php_id and $pic1 == $php_pic)
        {
           /* they are in same row*/
        }
```

**Method 2**

```
   /*Fetch records*/
      $sql = "SELECT id,pic1 from gallery where (id = $id and pic1=`$php_pic`)";
      $rs= $mysqli->query($sql);  /* fetch details */
      $row_cnt = $rs->num_rows;             


    /* match using php */
        if ($row_cnt >= 1)
        {
           /* they are in same row*/
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a condition for this:

```
   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM pica WHERE id=1 AND pic1='picture1') 
    SELECT 'verified' 
    ELSE 
    SELECT 'failed'
```